# Whether Virsh migrate VM works with xen hypervisor?

Tags: redhat, xen, libvirt

By referring https://libvirt.org/migration.html.. I tried VM migration between two libvirt servers

I tried instance migration with ssh, tls and tcp. In all three I got the same error as " this function is not supported by the connection driver"

Eg

**migrate --live  domuname  xen+tls://desthostname/system**

**error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virDomainMigrate3**

***My question is Whether live migration is supported with Xen hypervisor???***

Answer (score 0):

At time of asking, libvirt did not support this particular migration mode for the Xen driver. Since libvirt 1.2.6 the libxl driver should not support migration in this manner.